# how to reference value in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an a value in an array that I am not sure how to reference.

If I show the array like this:

```
 while (list($option, $value) = each($this->contents[$products_id]['attributes'])) {
     print_r( $this->contents[$products_id]['attributes']); echo "<br/>";   
}
```

I get the following output:

```
Array ( [5] => 115 [2] => 17 ) 
Array ( [5] => 115 [2] => 17 )
```

The value that I need is the 17.

Comment: Why the old PHP4 way to get through an array (with `list` + `each`) ? Even if for this problem, you should not even think about doing this kind of action

Comment: Can you please explain? This is not my code fully. What is the new way?

Comment: I should say, what is the php5 way of going through an array and why is this way so bad?

Comment: You have to use the `foreach` keyword : `foreach ($container as $key => $value) { /* actions */ }` (one line here, because on a SO comment, you can't paste multi line code ;). It is a loop, when on each turn, `$key` will be the key of the current element (equivalent of the first argument of `list`), and `$value` its value (2nd argument).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->contents[$products_id]['attributes'][2]
```

Comment: This works so thank you! And now looking at it seams obvious. I thought the 115 and the [2] were connected. doh